# Gerrit plugin/integration for Jira?

Tags: jira

Based on this link:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.meetme.plugins.jira.gerrit-plugin

it should be possible to integrate gerrit with jira. But when I go to the marketplace and search for **JIRA Gerrit Plugin** the plugin does not show up. I am running jira 6 has this plugin been disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the marketplace listing, it says that this is available for JIRA 5.0 to 5.2.x, so does not yet support JIRA 6 and will not be found when you do your search.

It's possible that it may work partially in JIRA 6, so downloading it from your link then installing on a test JIRA instance is completely possible.